# how to construct numbers without compass or a straightedge

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Given arbitrary lines of length a, b, 1. How would we construct stuff like a/b and square root of a without using a compass or straightedge

Comment: So you want to construct the numbers using nothing at all?

Comment: I think you will find the answer by listening to a one-handed man clapping.

Comment: Yes, without using any implements

Comment: Perhaps the OP has in mind that the line segments(!) of those lengths can be moved about in various ways.  The rules for such motions need to be spelled out.

Answer (score 2):

In case you change your mind about the use of implements,

[image]